# Did the top level menu font change permanently?

Tags: support, user-interface, design, fonts, top-bar

I noticed that Stack Overflow was looking somewhat different today but I couldn't figure out what was going on.  Until I compared an already open tab to a newly opened tab.

Did the top level menu font change from bold to non-bold or are my eyes playing tricks on me?

Already open menu:

[image]

New window menu:

[image]

I am seeing the new font in Chrome, Firefox.  I see the change on Stack Overflow as well as on Meta.  Is this a new permanent change?

Comment: I am curious, however, precisely what caused you to bemoan the change rather than to look in chat and check with someone there if they saw what you saw? Normally someone in chat can drag up a team member.

Comment: @jcolebrand I mainly asked because I cannot be the only person to notice the change or have a question about whether it actually did change. I looked around to see if anyone else asked about it first or if it was documented and I couldn't find it, now there is a record of it.  Sorry if you feel my question is unnecessary.

Comment: @jcolebrand I don't think that chat makes that much more sense here. Questions like this are solidly on-topic and whatnot on MSO and reach more people than chat typically does.

Comment: I felt it was as obvious as Shog's answer proves it to be, is all.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes.

Comment: was there some sort of outcry over the boldness of the menu?

Comment: The weeping and lamentation was deafening.

Comment: my eyes are having a hard time adjusting to the change.

Comment: It's rough; took me nearly two hours. Now I can't tell though.

Comment: well thanks for confirming the change.

Comment: No problem. I'll let our designer know that his work is noticed and appreciated!

Comment: Do you know why the font changed?  what was the reason for the change?

Comment: AFAIK, it just makes the header slightly cleaner and more consistent.

Comment: I liked the old one. Maybe I'll get used to the new one during the weekend.

Comment: Character limit FTW

Comment: [I DON'T LIKE CHANGE](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LHpdgHTINik)!

Comment: I'm _really_ tempted to expose your HTML comment :-).

Comment: I only noticed it now that you guys mentioned it. Can I open a new question to complain about that?